# How to convert DPI(Dots per Inch) of Camera images.?

Tags: ios, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am working on reading Identity Card information using Tesseract Library.Input Images are captured from Iphone camera at real time.Normally Captured images from Iphone are 72 DPI. But Tesseract have recommended to set 300 DPI.

My input image:

[image]

1.How to convert 300 DPI image programatically.?

2.Is any other method there in Opencv to Convert DPI.?

Comment: DPI in image processing is like sampling rate in audio/video - you can upsample to 300 DPI, but that can't automagically reconstruct original image in 300 DPI, because that information is simply lost as you scanned at 72 DPI. So it wont help tesseract either.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,you should know the normal size for the characters or numbers in the ID card when it is scanned with 300 DPI setting. Secondly, when you have the picture, you should identify the texts and numbers with page analysis method. In the meantime, you can calculate the statics of the connected components of the texts and numbers such as the width and the height of the texts. Then you compare with the connected component analysis results for the texts in the scanning condition, which can be stored as some auxiliary information in your program. Compared to the scanning situation, if the text size is larger, then you should downscale ; otherwise, upscale is needed.